# Npm start and Build is no longer working on my Windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, npm-start

I have been using npm for months to build projects and it's  suddenly stopped working 5 days ago on all my React projects.

Now, whenever I try to run `npm start` I get an error saying:

> ```
> project name @0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.
> ```

So, first I tried `npm install` again and then `start` but it didn't work so I tried `npm cache clean` and got an error saying:

> ```
> npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues...
> ```

and then the terminal told me to try `npm cache clean --force`. Then I got another error saying:

> ```
> npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
> ```

I have also tried  running `npm cache verify` and it didn't work. I even went as far as downloading and installing the latest version of node and still nothing.

and it's not just that i also tried doing "npm run build" on another app in another directory and it showed this

"amazon-clone@0.1.0 build

> react-scripts build

The system cannot find the path specified."

I checked and I'm using NPM version 7.9.0

please I'm stuck and I don't know what to do about

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem and I resolved this by,

1. Create a `.env` file in react project root directory.
2. Add this line `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`.

Comment: should i run it on the terminal "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true" ?

Comment: No add this line on `.env` file and save it. Now run `npm start`

Comment: pls where can i file the .env file on my windows

Comment: On your current project directory

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that I should create a .env file on my current directory and then add
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true?

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

It took a while but i found that running

"npm config set script-shell bash" on git bash
fix the issue but only on git bash